# Struggling with fetching and sorting RSS feeds in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, fetch

I'm new to react and react-native and struggling to understand what i'm doing so wrong in regard to a feedScreen component in React-Native. i had this working previously but after trying to implement a sorting function and useMemo I seem to have completely broken the component. It getting the information correctly, and then re-rendering which seems to clear out the intended data and leaves me with no information. Can anyone help me on this?

heres the FeedScreen component:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react"
import EpInfoCard from "./Cards/EpInfoCard"
import * as rssParser from "react-native-rss-parser"
import { FlatList } from "react-native"

export default function FeedScreen(props) {
    const feedName = props?.feedName

    const [episodeData, setEpisodeData] = useState([])

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState()

    const content = useMemo(() => {
        let result
        if (props.route.name === "SubscriptionsTabs") {
            return (result = [...props.subscriptions])
        } else if (props.route.name === "FeedTabs") {
            return (result = [...props.feedContent])
        }
        return result
    }, [props.subscriptions, props.feedContent])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("content: " + content.length)
        fetchRSSFeed(content)
    }, [content])

    function fetchRSSFeed(content) {
        console.log(": FetchRSSFeed " + content)

        const episodes = []
        content.forEach((item) => {
            fetch(item.rss)
                .then((response) => response.text())
                .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
                .then((rss) => {
                    const itemList = rss.items
                    const podImage = rss.image.url
                    console.log(itemList.length)
                    itemList.forEach((item) => {
                        let episodeImage
                        if (item.imageUrl !== undefined) {
                            episodeImage = item.itunes.image
                        } else {
                            episodeImage = podImage
                        }
                        const dateObj = new Date(item.published)
                        const date = dateObj.toDateString()
                        const dateNum = dateObj[Symbol.toPrimitive]("number")

                        episodes.push({
                            id: item.title,
                            pubDate: date,
                            pubDateNum: dateNum,
                            title: item.title,
                            mp3: item.enclosures[0].url,
                            epImage: episodeImage,
                            description: item.description,
                            duration: item.itunes.duration,
                        })
                    })
                })
        })
        setEpisodeData(episodes)
    }

    const sortedData = useMemo(() => {
        console.log("sorted data")
        let result = episodeData
        console.log("episode data: " + episodeData.length)

        if (props.feedSorting === "oldFirst") {
            result = [...episodeData].sort((a, b) => {
                a.pubDateNum - b.pubDateNum
            })
        } else {
            result = [...episodeData].sort((a, b) => {
                b.pubDateNum - a.pubDateNum
            })
        }
        return result
    }, [props.feedSorting, episodeData])
    console.log("sortedData: " + sortedData.length) 
// Initially returns 1400+ items, but then the useEffect aboves runs for some reason despite neither of the dependencies changing, setting the episodeData state correctly, then this return 0

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={sortedData}
            initialNumToRender={8}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <EpInfoCard
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                    setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                    key={item.id}
                    type="episode"
                    screen="episodesList"
                    contents={item}
                />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
            style={{
                padding: 10,
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Im expecting the the raw episodeData state to set once when the props are initiallized, then the sorting to happen and save the sortedData in useMemo, which is then rendered to the FlatList as the data object. Instead the items flash in upon render and then disappear, leaving my sortedData object empty. I'm imagining it has something to do with the order in which hooks happen, or perhaps the async nature of fetch, but i thought i did it like other examples ive seen on StackOverflow and various tutorial blogs, but clearly its not working. Any help would be appreciated.